# GETATTR issues with linux and netapp

Tags: linux, centos, nfs, netapp

We're having an issue with our linux systems connecting to our netapp via NFS. The read/write IOPS are only around 1000/s but the GETATTR calls are almost 10,000!

I found [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=321111) but it says, it was fixed in `kernel-2.6.18-92.el5` and we are on `2.6.18-274.el5`.

We are mounting these with `noatime`.

Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Disable access time on the NetApp volume, forget the client 'noatime' setting. You can run your IO load under `strace` and see what is being retrieved read from the export if needed (ie ratio of meta data to data IO).

Answer (score 0):

This is to improve the NFS performance as netapp is suggesting this file edit / config
modify or VI /etc/sysctl.conf
( add the following 2 lines and reboot sometime in the near future )

#Set the number of outstanding RPC requests that can be present on a single NFS connection
sunrpc.tcp_max_slot_table_entries=128